# How Do You Select Edge Loops In Weight Paint Mode

Tags: weight-painting

I want to paint an edge loop in weight paint mode. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Select your edge loop in edit mode

[image]

make sure face masking or vertex masking is active to only paint on previously selected face loop.

[image]

Comment: I realize this is a very old thead, but is there no way to set up this shortcut in weight paint mode? It should be possible.